# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I have the following function in my JavaScript code and when I run it shows me the following error `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` I am developing an SharePoint web application.

```
function startTest(quizID) {

   currentQuizItem = quizList.getItemById(quizID);
   var quizName;
   context.load(currentQuizItem);
   var userName = user.get_title();

   var audiencenames = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["Audienca"];
   var straudience = audiencenames.toString();
   straudience = straudience.toUpperCase();
   straudience = straudience.replace(/\s/g, '');

   userName = userName.toUpperCase();
   userName = userName.replace(/\s/g, '');
   var rezultati = straudience.match(userName);
   alert(rezultati);
}
```

please help me!

Comment: `console.log(audiencenames)` insert this after the assignment of value

Comment: still getting error :(

Comment: Check your audiencenames var, add check for undefined and null. As seems like your statement currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["Audienca"] returns nothing and then you want to use your toString to "nothing"

Comment: is audiencenames a number or string?

Answer (score 0):

`context.executeQueryAsync()` is what my code was missing. I Added it and it worked.

```
function startTest(quizID) {

    currentQuizItem = quizList.getItemById(quizID);
    var quizName;
    context.load(currentQuizItem);
    var userName = user.get_title();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var audiencenames = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["Audienca"];
            var straudience = audiencenames.toString();
            straudience = straudience.toUpperCase();
            straudience = straudience.replace(/\s/g, '');

            userName = userName.toUpperCase();
            userName = userName.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var rezultati = straudience.match(userName);
            alert(rezultati);
        },

        function() {
            // handle error
        });
}
```